# GCP Kubernetes all logs apears as error logs

Tags: kubernetes, stackdriver

I have a Kubernetes cluster.
All the container logs in the stack driver appear as severity:error.

The browser hass all the requests with status 200.

[image]

Is this normal?
Thanks

Comment: There's a deleted (why?) answer that links to a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124403972?pli=1

… AFAICT, it is, in fact, just bugged. Even *Go* logs, which logs structured logs with an explicit severity, show up with the wrong severity.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a GKE cluster it'll come preconfigured with pushing logs to Stackdriver. And as soon as you start your application on top of GKE, logs going to `stdout` or `stderr` from your containers and will be pushed to Stackdriver Logs by Fluentd.

Severity, that you can see in `Stackdriver -> Logging -> Logs viewer`, depends on where event was collected. So, if your application send event to `stderr` you'll found it with severity `ERROR` at Stackdriver.

Try to check where your application send events.

**EDIT** You can customize Stackdriver logs with Fluentd - follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/customizing-stackdriver-logs-fluentd).

Comment: `stderr` is the correct output for *all* logs, not merely errors. (The name is a misnomer.) Pretty much all *nix tooling is going to put logs, not merely errors, into that file descriptor, so if GCP is using "stdout vs stderr" to determine severity, then GCP Cloud Logs is doing it wrong.